# Python: Deleting duplicates from Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, append

When I output dfges, I get duplicates for a given element. For example, for Madrid the messages are all displayed three times each. Does anyone know a way to work around this problem or remove the duplicates? Is it possibly due to the upper For loop?

```
import ssl 
import smtplib 
import pandas as pd 
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews 
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    
googlenews = GoogleNews() 
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')     

Nachrichten = [
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_new) 
    nachrichten.append(df)

dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need a `dfges.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`. This will remove all duplicate rows. Note that two rows are considered duplicates only if they have the same values in each field (except the index).

See the doc for other details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Provide an example of your Dataframe `dfges` if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks! Do you probably know how I can make the urls clickable?

Comment: @David_Python please open another specific question about the URL, so that you can provide more information about your specific problem (example if you have to click URLS in a file, in the terminal, in a notebook etc...). This is an advantage for you because in this way you can reach more people.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now it is not possible to get one more question .. but my question is the following: How can I make the links in the URL column clickable? It would be important that not the entire URL is displayed, but perhaps only "To the article" is displayed, so that the URL behind "To the article" is deposited?

Answer (score 0):

As articles can be tagged with multiple locations e. g. `"Munich"` and `"Madrid"`, hence appear multiple times in your df, you should detect and delete duplicates using [`drop_duplicates(subset=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) based on the `'Title'` (and more criteria), as otherwise no duplicates are deleted add at all.

Your code could look like this:

```
...
dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
dfges.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)
print(dfges)
...
```